# Summarizing dataframe string values to count in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, summarize

in the screenshot below you'll find a dataframe that contains string values in each cell. What i would like to do is to create a new dataframe out of this one that contains 3 columns: 'Very interested' 'Somewhat interested', and 'Not interested'. I don't know how to transform the original df into  this new one, i tried just counting the values that meets a condition like 'Very interested' and putting them into a new df but the numbers don't seem right.

i would appreciate any help here. Thank you.

[image: Df to transform]
EDIT: here is also the code to reproduce a dataframe similar to the one in the screenshot:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({1: ['Very interested', 'Not interested', 'Somewhat interested', 'Very interested', 'Not interested', 'Somewhat interested'], 2: ['Very interested', 'Not interested', 'Somewhat interested', 'Very interested', 'Not interested', 'Somewhat interested'], 3: ['Very interested', 'Not interested', 'Somewhat interested', 'Very interested', 'Not interested', 'Somewhat interested'], 4: ['Very interested', 'Not interested', 'Somewhat interested', 'Very interested', 'Not interested', 'Somewhat interested'], 5: ['Very interested', 'Not interested', 'Somewhat interested', 'Very interested', 'Not interested', 'Somewhat interested'], 6: ['Very interested', 'Not interested', 'Somewhat interested', 'Very interested', 'Not interested', 'Somewhat interested']}, 
                 index=['Big Data','Data Analysis','Data Journalism', 'Data Visualization', 'Deep Learning', 'Machine Learning'])
```

As per the desired output, it should be something like this:

[image: Desired output]

Comment: Could you include your expected output dataframe in your post?

Comment: Please read up on [how to ask a good pandas question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).  Your code contains no usable input (because you pasted an image), no expected output, and shows no research effort.

Comment: @rahlf23 Sorry, i just edited the question and added what you were asking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need reshape by [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) and then get counts by [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) with [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = (df.rename_axis('val')
        .reset_index()
        .melt('val', var_name='a', value_name='b')
        .groupby(['val','b'])
        .size()
        .unstack(fill_value=0))
```

Another solution with[`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), counts by [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html) with [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = (df.stack()
        .groupby(level=0)
        .value_counts()
        .unstack(fill_value=0))
```

Comment: Hi @jezrael Thank you very much!! that was exactly what i'm looking for. I'm glad to see someone understood what i was asking :)

Comment: @Miguel2488 - There is problem in your question not possible copy data, you can improve your question by add `df = pd.DataFrame({1: ['vi', 'ni', 'ni'], 
                   2: ['vi', 'ni', 'vi'], 
                   3: ['vi', 'si', 'si'], 
                   4: ['si', 'vi', 'vi']}, index=['dv','ml','das'])` - be free modify it ;)

Comment: Allright, i'm editing it